# Using the Dev Board Mini as a USB Accelerator substitute

Tags: tensorflow

We have a RPi 4 with TF-L code.  We are testing this on a RPi but obviously the Vision Processing is very slow and we would like to test the processes using the TPU of a coral product.  The USB accelerator would be the easy choice to perform the TPU on the RPi, but they are not in stock of course.  Is there a way to use a Dev Board Mini to be setup similar to the USB accelerator stick?  Or will a RPi image work to flash on the #mini dev board?